# Logical move of a server to UK, what do I do with the SSL certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have been asked to move a rails application from the US to the UK. This involves bringing up the rails stack on Ubuntu 8.04.4; that's completed. I'm stumped with the SSL configuration though. The plan was to bring this server up with the same domain name but temporarily use a subdomain (`app2.xxx.com` instead of `app.xxx.com`) during the move and for testing, then rename it to app.xxx.com when we're ready for the cutover (does that make sense?). In the meantime, we need a new cert for the app2 subdomain. So to generate a CSR, I need a server key but do I need a new one, or should I copy the one from the existing production server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd just copy across the existing certificates and keys. Yes it'll complain whilst you're in testing on the new subdomain, but that'll go away as soon as you change it to the correct name.  Mind you I can be pretty lazy, and if you actually need a new ssl certificate for the temporary subdomain then go ahead with new everything - then copy the old one across when it's ready to go live on the current name.

Also, 10.04 is being released next week and is also an LTS version.  Don't know what your timeframe on launch is, and I'd probably want 10.04 to be released for a month or two before putting it on a live server, but it's worth considering.

Comment: we just dealt with the name mismatch for the duration of the testing period. The move went well.

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a certificate with a common name of `app2.xxx.com`. You need a new CSR for that new certificate.